# Adding to a value in a table on the press of a button on a webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I am very new to SQL and to say the least, I am struggling.

My table looks like this:

[image]

All I want to do is be able to increment any of these values by one upon the press of a button, like this:

[image]
This is how it looks on the website, but nothing is functional at all yet.

I have an understanding of HTML, CSS, and PHP, so if I were to know the correct way to do this with SQL, I should be able to implement it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I see people suggesting AJAX ("elsewhere" as well as here), but you are unfamiliar with this.  I'm going to suggest a completely non-Javascript solution, sticking with HTML, PHP, and MySQL, as you already know these.  I would definitely recommend learning Javascript at some point though.

I've no idea of your level of understanding, so please let me know any bits of the following code you don't follow, and i'll explain in more detail.

```
<?php

    /* Initialise the database connection */
    $db = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
    if ($db->connect_errno) {
        exit("Failed to connect to the database");
    }

    /* First, check if a "name" field has been submitted via POST, and verify it 
     * matches one of your names.  This second part is important, this
     * will end up in an SQL query and you should NEVER allow any unchecked 
     * values to end up in an SQL query.
     */
    $names = array("Anawhata","Karekare","Muriwai","Piha","Whatipu");

    if(isset($_POST['name']) && in_array($_POST['name'], $names)) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];

        /* Add 1 to the counter of the person whose name was submitted via POST */
        $result = $db->query("UPDATE your_table SET counter = counter+1 WHERE name = $name");
        if(!$result) {
            exit("Failed to update counter for $name.");
        }

    }
?>

<table>

<?php
    /* Get the counters from the database and loop through them */
    $result = $db->query("SELECT name, counter FROM your_table");
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><?php echo $row['name'];?></p>

            <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add One" />
            </form>
        </td>

        <td><?php echo $row['counter']; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php

    } // End of "while" each database record

?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use AJAX on sending the form to make calls to a php script that handles the mysql query and "adds one". You should put a hidden input with the name of the person you want to increment. That's if you don't want to refresh the page.

If you don't mind refreshing, make every button part of a form, and send to the same php file.

I recently came across a library, called meteor.js that is capable of doing all this. I have not yes tested it, though.

Comment: Do you have any example code to demonstrate this? Like the AJAX part to call a PHP "function", and the SQL statement I would use to add one to a column? Thanks